# Referring to Code in IBM.Data.DB2 makes that Assembly Unavailable to the rest of my Solution

Tags: c#, reference, db2, using

I have a C# console application with three assemblies: `Main`, `Common` and `Utilities`.

In a file in the `Main` assembly, `Main.cs`, I have the line:

```
using Utilities;
```

In a directory within the `Common` assembly, I have the DLL `IBM.Data.DB2.dll`.

In the `Utilities` assembly, I have a source module which accesses said **dll**.
Utilities have a Reference to `IBM.Data.DB2`.
In a source file within this assembly, `Util.cs`, I have the line:

```
using IBM.Data.DB2;
```

If, within a method in this file, I make any reference to code within the DB2 assembly, as in:

```
DbConnection c = new DB2Connection( _connectString );
```

I get an error compiling the `Main` assembly stating that the namespace name `Utilities` can not be found. `Utilities` compiles fine with or without the line. If I comment out the above line, everything compiles fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A helpful colleague came by and solved this for me in about five seconds.

Turns out that by default, when a new Console app is created in VS 2010, it gets a target framework of ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile". Changing this to ".NET Framework 4" made the problem go away.

Answer (score 0):

Been dealing with a similar issue in VS 2013. I checked the client profile build version, everything looked fine, and I finally realized that I needed to right-click on the References tab to add the projects I had included to my solution References.  I did this, and everything clicked!