# The type or namespace name 'CrystalDecisions' could not be found

Tags: crystal-reports

I've downloaded the SAP Addon (ver. 13.0.1) for visual studio 2010.
I've referenced 
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll
CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.dll

and others.
set copy local to true.
and yet I get this error !
Any Ideas ?

> The type or namespace name
>   'CrystalDecisions' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

Even on rpt and cs auto generated files....

Comment: solution found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found

Comment: This Q. has the solution: 
[the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK if this is using II7 then on the related application pool, select advanced settings and then Allow 32bit apps. should resolve the issue as even if you you install the 64 bit runtimes, you need the 32 bit ones too as not all of crystal is 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i checked assembly in VS 2010 project add reference option and could not found. So i tried to add missing assemblies by NuGet package. I search missing assembly name online and add required. It solved my problem.

Comment: Please clean and reformat your answer. "Question You cannot vote on your own post 0" might not be intended to be part of it. And focus on the actual solution.