# Selenium - Advanced User Interactions

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How can I be able to use AdvancedUserInteractions in C# with Selenium 2. I am getting namespace missing error. Should I add any .dll file?

Comment: Which interactions do you like to perform? mention specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Add this namespace in your using section:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
```

Then, you will have access to the Action class. Like:

```
        var zoomLevel = driver.FindElement(By.Id("navZoomInSlider"));

        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.DoubleClick(zoomLevel);
        action.Build();
        action.Perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found).