# type or namespace name '...' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, mef

This work's fine for another app that I'm transferring into this one. I've been stuck here for hours and google does not have much for MEF. the System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll is imported, yes. But still cannot get rid of this error.

I have this for my includes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using JSNet;
```

Affected code:

```
var catalog = new AggregatingComposablePartCatalog();
var mainAssemblyCatalog = new AttributedAssemblyPartCatalog(this.GetType().Assembly);
var jsNetCatalog = new AttributedAssemblyPartCatalog(typeof(Effect).Assembly);            
//var addInEffects = new DirectoryPartCatalog("Effects"); 

catalog.Catalogs.Add(mainAssemblyCatalog);
catalog.Catalogs.Add(jsNetCatalog);
//catalog.Catalogs.Add(addInEffects);
var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
```

Errors:

```
Error 1: The type or namespace name 'AggregatingComposablePartCatalog' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

Error 2: The type or namespace name 'AttributedAssemblyPartCatalog' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    

Error 3: The type or namespace name 'AttributedAssemblyPartCatalog' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    

Error 4: The type or namespace name 'CompositionContainer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: By "imported" do you mean that the assembly has been added as a reference to your project?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is completely legit, but i remember having this issue when the .net framework version was set to client profile. Can you check your app's framework reference? (assuming this is a console/windows app)

Comment: Explaining how annoyed you are doesn't really make a very descriptive title.

Comment: @SergeyAkopov: I'm willing to bet that's actually the issue. Post that as an answer and you've got a vote from me.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found

Comment: Yes the reference is added.. and I have no clue why this is. Framework is 4 client.

Comment: @iKonroi: As Sergey says in his answer, you need to change the target framework to .NET 4. You can't use Client Profile.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood You're clearly a post booster and read one line of the issue, go away I clearly said it's refranced 6 times.

Comment: No, that is incorrect.. I told you both my projects working and non-working are set to 4 Client profile. But mine does not work, and it's the exact same files just in another project. I have tried to set it to 4 and still same error. I've almost tried everything, it's been about 4 hours on this issue. I need some less obvious issues I'm about to trash my 3k lines of project and say screw it. Because this is key needed. And according to my project I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Check if your app's framework version is set to Client Profile. If it is, this is your problem. The assembly you're referencing likely isn't targeting Client Profile. Change it to .NET 4.0 (not 4.0 Client Profile)