# Rally .NET REST API with windows (desktop) application, reference issue

Tags: .net, rally

I am trying to use the Rally REST API in my windows (desktop) application. I have added a reference and it allowed me to use functions. But, I am having an issue when I compile it, it says there is reference issue: "The type or namespace name 'Rally' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Note that issue is with windows application only, with web application it is working well. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051382/type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found-are-you-missing-a-using-directi), check if you have your project set to target the client profile or the full framework.

I just verified with a working .net application I have here, I get the same error you report when changing target framework from ".NET Framework 4" to ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile". Reversing the change fixed the issue once more.