# Programatically Adding A Control - And Accessing it's parameters

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, dynamic-usercontrols

I have the following control:

```
public partial class Controls_ProductPanel : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private int _ProductID;
    public int ProductID
    {
        get
        {
            return _ProductID;
        }
        set
        {
            _ProductID = value;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I want be be able to add it to a page like this:

```
Controls_ProductPanel panel = new Controls_ProductPanel();
panel.ProductID = 2;
Page.Controls.Add(panel);
```

But Visual Studio doesn't seem to reconise `Controls_ProductPanel`

I get:

```
 The type or namespace name 'Controls_ProductPanel' could not be found. (Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve this, I had to put the register tag on the .aspx page. This allowed me to access it's type.

```
 <%@ Register TagName="ProductPanel" TagPrefix="uc" Src="~/Controls/ProductPanel.ascx" %>
```

Answer (score -1):

look at this thread:

> [The type or namespace name could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found)

hope it helps

Comment: It's not a client profiling issue. This is a Web Site, not a project, and certainly not a multi-project solution. The link you posted solves a namespace problem. This is a type.