# Could not add Reference from one project to another project in the same Solution

Tags: wcf

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

I have created WCF Service Library project named: ***EvalServiceLibrary***

I have created Windows Service project with name: ***WindowsServiceHost*** in the same solution.

Now, I have referenced ***EvalServiceLibrary*** inside ***WindowsServiceHost***.

When I build the solution, I am getting the following error:

> ***The type or namespace name 'EvalServiceLibrary' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)***

After some analysis, I found that it is happening to Windows Service Project type.

Can anybody please suggest the solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found

Answer (score 0):

As you said i created a new WCF library. Then added a windows service project to the same solution referred this WCF to the windows service and builded the solution. No issue came.

Did you did some code in the solutions? If so there will be the issue. Can you describe detaily?

Comment: Have you used VS-2012? My doubt is that this problem comes only is VS-2012.
After some more googling, I have found the following article:

How to: Host a WCF Service in a Managed Windows Service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms733069.aspx

I have to work on it, but don't know how far it is helpful.

Comment: Hi, I have used VS-2012 only. Anyway i will look deep into your issue.