# C# Setting Form 2 as Startup

Tags: c#, forms, startup

in c#, i want to set forum 2 as startup form from program.cs,
but when i try to change the code piece below
i get such an error

**before changing:**

```
static void Main()
        {

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
```

after changing:

```
static void Main()
    {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form2());
    }
```

the error is : **The type or namespace name 'Form2' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

All my changes are to write "Form2" instead of "Form1"

Comment: Well where does `Form2` actually 'live'? Within what namespace? (Open the designer up, view the code behind the designer, look at the top, what's the namespace? How does this differ from `Form1`?)

Comment: Check if the namespace inside the file Form2.cs is the same of Form1.cs

Comment: Did You add Form2 to the project with the context  menu of the project tree ?

Comment: they seem not to be in the same namespace

Comment: they got different namespaces but they are in the same project,

Comment: @AbdülberKaya, then you need to add that namespace as one of your `using`'s within `Program.cs`.

Comment: Google saves lives.. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found

Comment: one's namespace is WindowsFormsApplication1, and the other one's Uploader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comments, your form `Form2` lives within the `Uploader` namespace. If that is the *entire* namespace then:

At the top of `Program.cs`, add in:

```
 using Uploader;
```

**or**

If you are using Visual Studio, it has a handy feature that allows you to right-click on where the error occurs (the `Application.Run` line), and it will give you the option to *automagically* add in the `using` for you.

Comment: yeah, it worked fine, thanks for your quick help, you helped me so much