# Simple test using Selenium Web driver c#: cannot seem to figure out the errors

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to write a text in the main wikipedia page using Web Driver but i can't manage to figure out why do I have these errors?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main Page");
    IWebElement searchInput =  driver.FindElement(By.Id("searchInput"));
    searchInput.SendKeys("web driver");
}
```

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'Attributes' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Enigmatry.Selenium.Tools' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)
>
> Error 2   The type or namespace name 'SeleniumTestBase' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error 3   The type or namespace name 'IgnoreConfigAttribute' could not
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

I'm sorry for the noobness but I don't seem to figure what is `SeleniumTestBase` and where I've used it. Can someone advise me what to do?

Comment: this is not related to WebDriver but rather to your setup. I'm not a C# user but you can quickly find answers [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344295/im-getting-the-missing-a-using-directive-or-assembly-reference-and-no-clue-wh)

Comment: so what should i change in my set up? i've also tried to create another project but the issue is the same. all i am trying to do is take some text from a website and pass it into my textbox from my windows form application

Comment: Make sure you are importing Selenium (using OpenQA.Selenium)
Setting up a new project (basic console app) and adding the code [suggested here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334065/how-do-i-use-selenium-in-c) worked for me