# C# Git Project Missing Nuget Packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I have been facing an issue on my other machine where I clone my project from GitHub faced with the following missing references

[image: Reffernces Missing]

which I try to restore from NuGet but no use or success then I copy from the source machine and put it here but still unsuccessful

Comment: I usually solve this issue by cleaning the solution and then running it (ignore the errors), if this doesn't work then delete the obj and bin file then run it or just manually add the references.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm getting the "missing a using directive or assembly reference" and no clue what's going wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344295/im-getting-the-missing-a-using-directive-or-assembly-reference-and-no-clue-wh)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways this problem can be assisted by the following.

1. You may not have the same versions of .Net framework.
2. You may be able to do this in the following way
   you can clean bin and obj then

   1. Right click on the Solution -> Clean solution
   2. Right click on the Solution -> Rebuild solution

Answer (score 0):

1.In VS2015 and above, VS requires you to download corresponding framework when loading the project.

[image]

So at least you've installed the corresponding framework. For `System.dll,System.core.dll...`, they are assemblies from .net framework. You can `close the solution=>restart VS and reload the solution` to resolve the warnings about system.xxx assemblies. If the warning persists, try [repairing your .net framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/repair).

2.For `EntityFramework.dll` and `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll`, they're coming from `EntityFramework` package. Please check your project file(xx.csproj) and make sure there's statements like these:

[image]

Then navigate to the hintpath to check if the required assembly exists there. (solution dir/packages/xxx). If you restore the packages to other specific path, just modify the hintpath element and make VS can find those assemblies, the warning would go away.