# Showing error even if i have given required reference...?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, reference

I am getting following error when i am trying to build my c# project:

> *The type or namespace name xyz could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

I have given reference of required file . don't know why this error is coming again and again?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you add `using` directive top of your code?

Comment: @dcastro It is not [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx), it is [using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx). These are 2 different things `;)`

Comment: yes , I have used 'using' keyword on the top

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the using directive too. In the file that is throwing the error, add:

```
using xyz;
```

Obviously substituting `xyz` with the correct namespace.

Comment: Try cleaning and then rebuilding your entire solution - it may be that the `using` directive is needed in other files too...

Comment: Cleaned and rebuild but nothing improved .. still shoeing same error..!!

Comment: Can you post the full error message, and then the `using` block from the file that is referencing?

Comment: yes... here it is:   _Error 2 The type or namespace name 'SensorControl' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Documents and Settings\Anita\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WFM2_V1.6\WFM2_V1.6\settingFrm.cs 12 7 WFM2_V1.6_        and using block is    **using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;


using SensorControl;
using SensorControl.Sensors;
using PaintAnalysis.Common;**

Comment: Could be that the project has the wrong [client profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found?rq=1)

Comment: It's explained in the link I provided.