# the namespace "system" could not be added to the project

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2013, portable-class-library

I am working on a C# PCL.  The targets include Windows Phone, iOS, and Android (all via Xamarin).  Whenever I add a new class, I get a popup starting with "The namespace system could not be added to the project."  It then proceeds me to warn me that things might not work.  Well, they do work, but the popup is annoying.  Can I stop it?

Comment: Ah... you are not alone. I have the same problem:

The reference "System" could not be added to the project. This wizard will continue to run, but the resulting project may not build properly.

Comment: I have this problem too. Is this xamarin's fault?

Comment: Are you on the alpha or stable channel for xamarin items? I had this issue happen to me as well, but mine was when I would create a PCL(Profile 78/158) from XS and open it withing VS. Have you tried to just re-reference system?

Comment: Can you post a link to a repository or [gist](http://gist.github.com) on [github](http://github.com)? Maybe a step-by-step guide to reproduce the problem also.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is a problem with the Framework version of the `namespace system`and your project.
Confirm they both match the same framework.

I recommend you take a look [over this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b0f069e7-398e-416b-8358-7a66a5ebbeff/type-or-namespace-could-not-be-found-missing-directive-assembly-reference?forum=csharpgeneral), which addresses a similar kind of issue. Usually when the references are not proper, you may get [this kind of issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found).