# Unable to add reference to BouncyCastle after NuGet import

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, reference, bouncycastle

I am trying to link to the BouncyCastle library in my ASP.NET MVC 5 application.  I right clicked on my project, and went to the NuGet Packages.  I installed BouncyCastle and I now see it in my references as BouncyCastle.Crypto.  I want to use this package, so just like anything else I am trying:

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto
```

When I do this, I get an error that `The type or namespace 'Org' could not be found`.  If I try `using BouncyCastle.Crypto` I get the same error, except this time for the type or namespace `BouncyCastle`.

If I grep for BouncyCastle, I can see it in my packages:

```
packages/BouncyCastle.1.7.0/lib/Net40-Client/crypto.xml:        <member name="T:Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader">
```

One thing that I notice, however, is that it comes up as `Net40-Client`.  Is this an issue?  Was it built using a client profile?  If so, it seems similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found).  However, I am not sure how to actually change this profile if this is the case, since it is a pre-built library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the `using` in the same project where the DLL has been added as a reference?

Edit 1: I just tried that and it is working for me. Please verify if you are using it in relevant project.

Comment: sigh, you're right.  I forgot that I was editing a helper function in a different project that is still within the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.  Eventually I noticed that BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll (which was in the correct project's bin folder) wanted me to right click on it and select "Include in Project".  This was the fix I needed to succssfully reference the bouncy castle classes =^.^=

Answer (score 0):

right click the project click unload then reload.

you should then see BouncyCastle in the references folder in the project.

Comment: to add to this do a clean and a build of the project this will get it to build again

Comment: You can edit your post instead of adding comments ;)