# Topshelf: cannot build from sources

Tags: c#, topshelf

I try to build topshelf from sources but receive the error:

```
 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Internals' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have checked but found only

```
using Internals.Extensions
using Internals.Cache
```

and did not find Internals namespace definition 
What is wrong?

I have got sources from github and try to build.
No any changes in code and project.

Comment: Also look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626826/error-the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found-during-a-build-process

Comment: No, it is another question. Your link did not help, I am sure that is specific problem of 'topshelf'.

Comment: happy to re-open but I assure you this is not an error specific to TopShelf, its a very general error when you've not referenced the right assembly

Comment: thnx. Sorry, but I only get sources and try to build. No changes in code. As I understand it must build without any interventions to code. May be somebody already fixed this kind of problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This project is using Git submodules. Because of that, after cloning, you don't have the full set of required sources yet. You also need to run `git submodule init` and `git submodule update`. Or, just `git submodule update --init`.

Or, use `git clone --recursive` in your initial clone command to automatically get the submodules as well.

These commands are already listed in the `readme.md` file. You just weren't paying enough attention.

Comment: Hardly obvious! Those commands are under a "Contributing" heading - If I dont want to contribute, but just wish to get the code and build it the "Download code" link does not work "out of the box". This is a badly set up project.

Comment: @Jamiec Actually, the "Download the code" link does work out of the box. It doesn't get you the source code, it gets you the pre-compiled package. But you're right that the `git submodule init`/-`update` commands are listed under "Contributing". The "Source" section is more appropriate. It uses `git clone --recursive`, which has the same effect. Edited to mention that.