# How to solve this error "DatePickerControl couldn't be found"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications

I moved asp .NET project(web application) to another computer. When I tried to build it, it showed this error

The type or namespace name 'DatePickerControl' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

the code

```
<%@ Register Assembly="DatePickerControl" Namespace="DatePickerControl" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<cc1:DatePicker ID="DPDateInInput" runat="server" AllowType="False" DateFormat="d/M/yyyy" StartWeekWithDay="Sunday" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found

Comment: @Sajeetharan - that seems to be about 4.0 vs 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DatePickerControl was added to the GAC (Global Assembly Cache) on the other environment.  You need to link to it in options or add it to the GAC on this machine.

It may also be that referenced assemblies in your project points to an invalid path, so check that too.

To link it in options go to the options you can go to reference paths and add a path to the location of the dll.

Comment: how to link it in options?