# Not able to use reference class in C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2008

I have added one reference "ABC.xyz.dll" to my project in visual studio. But i am not able to use it in my class file. 
like "**Using ABC.xyz**."
It gives me error "The type or namespace name "ABC" could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)".
Any help or suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure that's the actual namespace name? It might not always be the same as the DLL name

Comment: try close Visual studio then clean + build + rebuild..works sometime

Comment: @Neel Tried that. but still same.

Comment: @shree.pat18 That is exactly what code in class file with that DLL contains. "ABC.xyz". And I checked. Its the same namespace.

Comment: Could also be a Client Profile issue. Tkae a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found