# Added a project but it says its missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

So I added a project to my solution, it builds, but I can't seem to reference it, as it says its missing.  I've looked and tried all the answers here:

[The type or namespace name could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found)

but none worked for me.  all projects are set to target .NET Framework 4.5, Site project is dependant on the reference project, they all have the same Configuration Properties (Debug, Any CPU, Build)...

Any other ideas?

[image]

Comment: You did build that project at least once right?

Comment: Yes, I built it separately more than a few times.  Also tried removing it and adding it back, restarting VS

Comment: Do you see `DataTables.Mvc` project in the `References` list of your target project?

Comment: ohhhh! nope, ok I added it and that fixed it.  DUH! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be wrong but i think a depency is only used for build order.
Did you add the project as a reference via Project folder => References(Right click on it) and select Add Reference...
Then open Solution,Projects and check the project that holds the namespace you are using(in your case DataTables.mvc)

Images for clarity :
[image]
[image]

Comment: How I added it was to r-click on the solution, add existing project, and browse to the project folder/.csproj file.

Comment: when you say "Project folder"  is this in Visual Studio or Windows Explorer or ...?  Because I don't see a "References" when I r-click.

Comment: In visual studio open the Project folder. There is a subfolder references. Right click on that folder and click Add Reference ... Do not select a specific file, visual studio should show you a list of your projects

Comment: ok, i see thanks that solved it! I didn't add the reference in my project... whoops