# The type or namespace name 'xxxx' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference in c#

Tags: c#, portable-class-library, .net-framework-version

I have a solution with 5 class libraries. I built these classes with .NET 4.5, but I had to change the version of .NET to 4, so I change all of these class libraries to 4, and now I get this error:

> The type or namespace name 'InvoiceRepository' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

All class libraries have the same version of .NET (i.e. 4), but I get the same error.
I googled it and I found that NuGet should be removed and should be installed again.  I did that but I get the same error.

[image]

best regards

Comment: The assembly containing InvoiceRepository is listed in references?

Comment: Have you done a clean/rebuild?

Comment: where is your class InvoiceRepository ? In which namespace ? Can u put using namespacewhereInvoiceRepositoryIs on top

Comment: @christophano ye i did

Comment: @PrasaanthNeelakandan yes i can

Comment: possible duplicate of [The type or namespace name could not be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found)

Comment: check the project which contain this class and build it individually and go up to check the dependencies hierarchy chain

Comment: @PrasaanthNeelakandan i can put it on the top ,but same error

Comment: Which NuGet packages are *InvoiceRepository* referencing? Do all NuGet packages target .NET 4.0, or could it be that at least some of them only target .NET 4.5?

Comment: Yes exactly one of them has a package in appconfig with .net4.5

Comment: So the *InvoiceRepository* project itself cannot be built right now? Which NuGet package requires .NET 4.5?

Comment: @AndersGustafsson no ,it can be built itself ,the ttms library can't be built ,the ttms has a reference to invoicerepository,the docx nuget needs .net4.5