# Unity3D error CS0246: The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

This is the errors when i build my game for Universal Windows 10 (Unity3D)

> Unity3D error CS0246: The type or namespace name could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference

My Question is Unique because it has different Compiler Errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The type or namespace name could not be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found)

Comment: Assets\Scripts\Network\FixNetwork.cs(7,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NetworkPlayer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Assets\Scripts\Network\FixNetwork.cs(14,35): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NetworkDisconnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Assets\Scripts\Player\CharacterValues.cs(24,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BitStream' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Assets\Scripts\Player\CharacterValues.cs(24,51): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NetworkMessageInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Assets\Scripts\Player\PlayerAnimations.cs(255,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RPC' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Yes, but in Unity3D (I have this error when i building my game for windows 10) (and the type or namespace name is different)

Comment: whats stopping you from adding the correct namespace?

Comment: I am adding the correct namespace

Comment: well, you obviously aren't otherwise you wouldn't get the exception

Comment: Can you please help me to fix these errors step by step, Thank you :)

Comment: and sorry, i am new to the stackoverflow community.

Comment: do you have red squiggly lines under your code in visual studio?