# The type or namespace name `****' could not be found

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

when i using unity3d ,and switch to android platform,there have a error in console. but the project can run at ios platform and no error.
there is the error's description ：

> Assets/Best HTTP (Pro)/BestHTTP/HTTPProtocolFactory.cs(31,63): error
>   CS0246:
>
> The type or namespace name `WebSocket' could not be found. Are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

who can solution this error，thanks for you。

Comment: What Unity version?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found