# Errors in establishing connection string between c# console application and crm

Tags: c#, crm

I have been trying the following code and error is:

> the type and namespace named **crmConnection** could not be found.

```
var connection = new CrmConnection();
var service = new OrganizationService(connection);
var context = new CrmOrganizationServiceContext(connection);
var connection = CrmConnection.Parse("Url=https://xyz.crm.dynamics.com;Username=username1;Password=password1);
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: You need to import the library where `CrmConnection` is or give the full namespace.

Comment: Have you added a reference to the dll? Read [this duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found), it might be helpful

Comment: Does it work if you add `using Microsoft.Xrm.Client;` to the top of the file?

Comment: There is no class names Client in Microsoft.Xrm. So that does not work. @DavidG

Comment: There is no class names Client in Microsoft.Xrm. So that does not work. @DavidG

Comment: So then you need to add a reference to it. This is rather basic C# fundamentals, perhaps you need to run through a tutorial first?

Comment: using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk; contains the client class but the application is not able to find it. How to do that? @DavidG

Comment: Thank you @TimSchmelter but I am not able to understand the basics. Any further suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to get the CRM SDK if you dont have it already, then add a reference to the `Microsoft.Xrm.Client` assembly which contains `CrmConnection`.

Comment: There is no Microsoft.Xrm.Client as it is included in Microsoft.Xrm.Client.

Comment: @Max410, that's a very confusing comment, what do you mean?

Comment: There is no Microsoft.Xrm.Client as it is included in Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk. mistyped it. Sorry

Comment: Not according to the MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.client.crmconnection(v=crm.7).aspx

Comment: @Max410, on StackOverflow instead of thanks you can just upvote or accept the useful answers (http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

I use the following method to connect to the CRM OrganizationService, because I had problems with CrmConnection and Tooling.CrmConnector. This method has been tested for on premise installation with internet facing deployment.

Replace `{OrganizationName}` and `{Servername}` with the name of the CRM Organisation and URL of the CRM Server. For example: `OrganizationName = "xyz", Servername = "crm.dynamics.com"`.

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

string serviceUri = "https://{OrganizationName}.{Servername}/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc";
var credentials = new ClientCredentials();
credentials.UserName.UserName = "YourUsername";
credentials.UserName.Password = "YourPassword"; 
var crmOrganizationService = new OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri(serviceUri), null, credentials, null);
```

To install the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk package in a VS project, do the following:

- right-click on Solution Node in Soltion exploerer, choose "Manage NuGet packages for Solution"
- in NuGet Explorer, choose "Browse" and search for "CRM SDK 2016"
- Choose `Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies`, select the project into which you want to install the package, and click "Install"

Comment: I did that but it is not helping. Thanks @georg Patsheider

Comment: Do you get any errors while installing the package? Your project must target .NET Framework 4.5 or higher if you want to use version 8 of the SDK. Package Manager errors are written to the "Output" window.