# web service error CS0246: The type or namespace name could not be found VS2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web-reference

I've added both a Web Service and a Web Reference to my project and can consume neither (one of which I named emsBookings) appropriately because I get the following error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'emsBookings' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I tried using:

```
using emsBookings;
```

But that did not resolve the issue - and instead the error pointed to that line when I added that code.

My code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;



namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string xmlRequest;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            WebApplication1.emsBookings.GetAllBookingsRequestBody client = new WebApplication1.emsBookings.GetAllBookingsRequestBody();

            //inputs required for request
            string username = "theusername";
            string password = "thepassword";
            DateTime startDate = System.DateTime.Today;
            DateTime endDate = System.DateTime.Today;
            int buildingID = 36;
            bool viewCombo = false;

            client.UserName = username;
            client.Password = password;
            client.StartDate = startDate;
            client.EndDate = endDate;
            client.BuildingID = buildingID;
            client.ViewComboRoomComponents = viewCombo;

            emsBookings.GetAllBookingsRequest request = new emsBookings.GetAllBookingsRequest();
            request.Body = client;

            xmlRequest = request.Body.ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

Is there a specific way I need to reference the web-reference and/or web-service in order to use it in my code?

In Web.Config I find reference to emsBookings in the following:

```
<configuration>
    //Extra stuff removed for brevity
    <appSettings>
        <add key="emsBookings.Service" value="https://my.fully.qualified.server/THEAPI/Service.asmx"/>
```

I've tried:

- rebuilding (no success)
- cleaning / rebuilding (no success)
- adding 'using emsBookings;' (no success)

Any other ideas on what to try?

I'm fairly limited in my access to the server, so digging through logs in the root C: drive or things like that I would like to *try* to avoid if possible.

This is *not* a duplicate as far as I can tell as I am targeting .NET 3.5 and in the Property Pages, the build Target Framework is .NET Framework 3.5; I cannot find any reference to a Client Profile anywhere which was the indicated issue in the other 'possible duplicate' question.

Here is a link to the VS2010 showing the service reference added to my application: https://i.stack.imgur.com/en0jQ.jpg

Here is a link showing that the service reference exists in the same namespace (object browser): https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e6Y7.jpg

Here is some of the Reference.cs:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18444
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace WebApplication1.emsBookings {
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System;


    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute(Name="ArrayOfInt", Namespace="http://DEA.EMS.API.Web.Service/", ItemName="int")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public class ArrayOfInt : System.Collections.Generic.List<int> {
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute(Name="ArrayOfString", Namespace="http://DEA.EMS.API.Web.Service/", ItemName="string")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public class ArrayOfString : System.Collections.Generic.List<string> {
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://DEA.EMS.API.Web.Service/", ConfigurationName="emsBookings.ServiceSoap")]
    public interface ServiceSoap {

        // CODEGEN: Generating message contract since element name GetAPIVersionResult from namespace http://DEA.EMS.API.Web.Service/ is not marked nillable
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://DEA.EMS.API.Web.Service/GetAPIVersion", ReplyAction="*")]
        WebApplication1.emsBookings.GetAPIVersionResponse GetAPIVersion(WebApplication1.emsBookings.GetAPIVersionRequest request);
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a reference to emsBookings in your project solution explorer?

Comment: downvotes without reasons behind them are not helpful. I have googled this extensively - obviously none of the solutions listed have helped me, which is why I posted here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The type or namespace name could not be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found)

Comment: @JayGould - there is a reference to that in my project solution explorer. I added it via the menu 'Website -> Add Service Reference', so it was inserted programatically.

Comment: This is bizarre, the Service class that was created is that in the same project? I assume it is and its in the same namespace. (namespace is missing in the above code snippet)

Comment: @Hyder you can see it here: http://imgur.com/hIOCqKJ it's in the same project

Comment: @Hanny is emsBookings in the same namespace?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes it is. It's in the same project.

Comment: @JayGould - yes, it is in the same namespace. I can confirm - but it still claims it's not once I run the web application. I can't figure this out - the other solutions on SO don't work for me either.

Comment: @Hanny can you put the code for emsBookings in please?

Comment: @JayGould I updated the original question with additional information - let me know if some of it isn't clear

Comment: @JayGould - did that information help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed from your screenshot that you have created a website and that is referenced in the solution?

If you have, its better to create an ASP.NET Web Application and create the service reference again, as from what you have explained.

I have performed my own suggestion the reference has worked as expected.

Comment: Originally I had created it as a website and I see now that doing the web application lends itself to some different verbiage being added to the .aspx file (as well as additional backend files being generated). 

I have run into some other issues - but I believe they are more related to server setup than issues with the programmatic code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problems, there are some good resources provided by Microsoft to help in creating new Web Applications. I would look at Asp.Net MVC. Its very different to the web page style that you are doing here but it is more desirable skill set than Asp.Net Web Pages

Comment: For MVC stuff I tend to use PHP and most my of development is all PHP / Ruby on Rails based. This is my first jump into any .net / ASP stuff (although, I admittedly did some Classic ASP) a year or so ago.

I posted a question about my further issues if you care to have a gander - it's about changing the TEMP directory where files are being generated as our sys admins are against granting access to core directories:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39002532/xmlserializer-tempfileslocation-attribute-is-not-allowed-net-3-5-showing-de