# What is the reason for getting this error?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

DataConnections panel ->

[image]

Solution Explorer panel->

[image]

Here i'm getting error "**Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FoodieWeb' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**"

"S**ource File: C:\Users\Bhagi\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\245b4bf4\46b856c3\App_Web_signup.cshtml.65793277.spugtxdf.0.cs    Line: 28**"

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4765076/6741868

Answer (score 0):

The error means that somewhere in your source code you are using something named "FoodieWeb", but the compiler does not know what that is because the definition of "FoodieWeb" is not found.

1. Go and search your solution for the place where "FoodieWeb" is declared.
2. If there is no hit, then you are likely missing an external reference. Then you have to know the assembly where this type is defined and add a reference to that assembly.
3. If there is a hit, but it is in another project, please make sure that the project using "FoodieWeb" contains a reference to the other project.
4. Also make sure that you have added a `using` directive at the top of the file where you are using "FoodieWeb" which tells the compiler in what namespace "FoodieWeb" is contained.