# The type or namespace 'System' could not be found. Fresh Install of Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I've just installed a brand new version of Visual Studio 2017. I attempted to create a new cross-platform app using Xamarin.forms, and I instantly have errors

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    App1.UWP    C:...\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\App1\App1\App1\App.xaml.cs    1   Active

I am not sure what to do. I tried restarting- basic things like that. I couldn't get anything to work. Does anyone know why I might not have access to something as simple as System? It says it occurs in the project 'App1.UWP'

Thanks

Comment: Exact same problem here. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The type or namespace name could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found)

Answer (score 0):

A random shot in the dark but check the build properties of the file.

If it's a xaml file it should be set to embedded resource otherwise it's set to c# compiler. I had this issue previously where my visual studio for some reason set the build option to none instead of c# compiler or embedded resource.