# accessing files from a difference namespace c#

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have created a project structure like below

```
-Project.sln
  --Provider.csproj
  ---Middleware
  ----Helper.cs
  ---Tests.csproj
  ----test1.cs
```

I am trying to access `Helper.cs` from `test1.cs` like `using Provider.Middleware`, but build is failing with message: 
`The type or namespace name 'Middleware' does not exist in the namespace 'Provider'`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have multiple projects?

Comment: is `Helper.cs` accesible? it sounds like you made this class static.

Comment: yes. Tests.csproj and Provier.csproj.

Comment: have you added `Provider.csproj` project as dependence to `test.csproj`?

Comment: all classes defined as 'public class'

Comment: You need to add a reference to your `Tests.csproj` which points to your `Provider.csproj`.

Comment: cool! I think this worked, let me check thoroughly.

Comment: Sure, upvote the comment if I could help you.

Comment: now Im getting this: obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Providers.Program.cs(4,7): error CS0101: The namespace '<global namespace>' already contains a definition for 'AutoGeneratedProgram' [D:\Providers\Providers.csproj]
obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Providers.Program.cs(3,2): error CS0579: Duplicate 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestSDKAutoGeneratedCode' attribute [D:\\Providers\Providers.csproj]

Comment: any idea on how to get ride of AutoGeneratedProgram error

Comment: You need to specifiy the namespace explicitly using the `namespace` keyword. Directory structure is only a convention

Comment: yes, all classes have namspace in them. Like test1.cs is under namespace 'Tests'

Comment: The error you posted in a previous comment indicates that you actually do not have a namespace used at all points as it contains "<global namespace>". Please post the code from the cs-Files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The type or namespace name could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you have `Middleware`  as a folder in your project and something like this in your Helper class:

```
namespace Provider.Middleware{

…

}
```

Comment: this is solved, I'm now stuck at <globalnamespace> issue.