# Problem with Extending The SuperTiled2Unity Importer in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to code a custom importer for the **SuperTiled2Unity** plugin in Unity. This task is explained in the pugin documentation: [here](https://supertiled2unity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/extending-the-importer.html#custom-importers). My problem is that Unity don't seem to be aware that the plugin is installed which is weird because it works perfectly while the plugin import a tiled map. The problem occurs when a call the plugin in a script:

```
using SuperTiled2Unity;
using SuperTiled2Unity.Editor;
using UnityEngine;


/*
* Tells SuperTiled2Unity to used this importer by default
* */
[AutoCustomTmxImporter()]
public class MapImporter : CustomTmxImporter
{

    public override void TmxAssetImported(TmxAssetImportedArgs args)
    {
        // Note: args.ImportedSuperMap is the root of the imported prefab
        // You can modify the gameobjects and components any way you wish here
        // Howerver, the results must be deterministic (i.e. the same prefab is created each time)
        SuperMap map = args.ImportedSuperMap;
        //Debug.LogFormat("Map '{0}' has been imported.", map.name);
        // Find all tracks in our maps. These are edge colliders under the "Track" layer
        EdgeCollider2D[] edgeCollider2Ds = map.GetComponentsInChildren<EdgeCollider2D>();
        foreach (EdgeCollider2D collider in edgeCollider2Ds)
        {
            if (collider.gameObject.layer == LayerMask.NameToLayer("Block_Bullet"))
            {
                Rigidbody2D rb = collider.gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
                rb.isKinematic = true;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Then Unity gives me these compilation errors:
[image: Unity error console]

What is strange is that VisualStudio seems to know that **SuperTiled2Unity** exists and thus, doesn't throw any compilation error.

At this time, I already tried to:

1. Re-import the **SuperTiled2Unity** plugin
2. Put my class in a namespace

I am aware that this issue seems like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found) but I don't know how to use this solution. If this is relevant, please explain me how to apply it.

I use the 1.9.3 version of **SuperTiled2Unity** whit Unity 2020.1.3f1.

**EDIT:**
I run the examples provided with the **SuperTiled2Unity** plugin on [Github](https://github.com/Seanba/SuperMovingPlatform) and the only difference I'm spotting is the *assembly informations*:
[image: Assembly information of my script]
[image: Assembly information the example script]

Could it be the cause of my problem ? If so, how to solve it ?

Comment: Try to move your script outside the `Editor` folder ... editor folders have a special meaning in Unity. Maybe the [compilation order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompileOrderFolders.html) is a problem and Unity doesn't "know" these types yet

Comment: @derHugo Unfortunately, it changes nothing.

Comment: Maybe go to the according plug-in folder and check if it is supported for your target platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got your own scripts in your own `Assembly Definition` named `NewAssembly`. However, that assembly definition does not have an `Assembly Definition Resource` for `SuperTiled2Unity` and `SuperTiled2UnityEditor`.

Either fix your `NewAssembly` assembly definition or remove it and you should be able to compile your custom importer.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin is in it's own assembly definition. It's likely set up only be referenced by specific other assemblies that need it. Try putting your scripts that use SuperTiled2Unity in the same folder as SuperTiled2Unity's scripts. This will make it part of the same assembly. If that works then you either need to keep it there or set the SuperTiled2Unity assemblies to be referenced by your extension's assembly definition.