# Build is failing with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am facing a problem in an attempt to debug the code in Visual Studio 2012. I have series of the class files and the Asp.Net pages in a single solution file. The Asp.Net pages call functions in the class libraries and get the required details.

Everything worked well until I upgraded my license from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2012. The problem is that reference to the assemblies are lost and the build is failing. Additionally the Dlls after the compilation of the individual class file project are deleted.

Please let me know if someone has faced similar problem and resolution.

Thanks,
Yagya

Comment: Have you tried deleting then reattaching the References?

Comment: Yes. I have done this several times.

Comment: Were there any noteworthy errors or warnings when you converted/imported the site into VS 2012? Did you change the .NET version?

Comment: All errors are related to missing reference where the namespace of an assembly is not detected by another one. The surprising part is that each project compiles fine individually with the references to other assemblies. The problem start arising when .cs files of the libraries are added to the ASp.net project and try to compile the whole solution. Another observation is that Dlls from the Bin folder are deleted after I compile the overall solution.

Comment: Are all your projects using the same version of .NET? I had a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286599/referenced-project-gets-lost-at-compile-time) a few years ago.

Comment: Thanks Bob for the hint. All projects except one were using .Net framework version 4.0. I changed the version and it worked like a charm. Thanks again for the assistance.