# The type or namespace name 'X' could not be found

Tags: c#

I have a CustomerOrderContext class in CustomerOrder.Data project in my solution. In another project, CustomerOrder.App, I have CustomerVM class. In this class I'm creating a CustomerOrderContext instance. But I get this following error:

> Error    2   The type or namespace name 'CustomerOrderContext' could not
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

I have changed  Build Actions of both projects to Page and then back to None and I have started to get this error. I have this line in CustomerVM:

```
using CustomerOrder.Data;
```

so I guess I shouldn't get this error. CustomerOrder.Data is also in References list of CustomerOrder.App. Can you tell me how I can fix this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the build order of these 2 projects?

Comment: @shree.pat18 CustomerOrder.Data  is built first.

Comment: What's the framewrok you used for both project

Comment: @MoezRebai I used .NET Framework 4.5 for both projects.

Comment: Could you try to rebuild them with framework 4

Comment: @MoezRebai I'm getting a lot of errors. I think I'm using many framework 4.5 libraries.

Comment: Are you sure CustomerOrderContext is in namespace CustomerOrder.Data? Reference to CustomerOrder.Data means assembly named CustomerOrder.Data, but given your "using CustomerOrder.Data", said assembly should contain namespace with the same name as well. Use Object Browser to check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is solved when I created new project, copied & pasted all classes.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add Reference of that project (.dll) in your project.

You will find it when you right click your solution and add the (.dll) of other project in debug folder.
To access the class you must have same namespace

and
 Check that both projects follow the same .Net Framework

Comment: Check that both projects follow the same .Net Framework

Answer (score 0):

be sure that CurstomerOrderContext class is marked as Public and not Internal.

Comment: It is public and not internal.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the framework versions are compatible?  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4286625/2478357.

Also, if you use Entity Framework (and *CustomerOrder.Data*  uses EF), check if your *CustomerOrder.App* has a reference to the Entity framework dll. *(This also applies to other imported dll's..)*