# VS 2010 error: the type namespace name could not be found(are you missing assembly)

Tags: c#

I am working on a web application in  Visual Studio 2010. I have added some dll's which is integrated using Microsoft and some other application... I added dll's in my web app. When I build it then it shows

> the type namespace name could not be found(are you missing assembly).

When I refresh it then all classes highlighted and error goes and I am unable to build and publish it. I am using .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: What target framework in your project? .NET Framework 4.0 or .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile?

Comment: can you please explain a bit more, which all assemblies causing problem for you ?

Comment: How did you add these dll's?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The type or namespace name could not be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found)

Comment: Also please see [Getting “type or namespace name could not be found” but everything seems ok?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3304741/4275342)

Comment: Need to know how you are ading the dll's

Comment: And look at [Referenced Project gets “lost” at Compile Time](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4286599/4275342)

Answer (score 0):

The Project which is is referencing the Assembly may have different framework type from the assembly.

for example:
Forms Project was set to ".Net Framework 4 Client Profile" if you change it to ".Net Framework 4", it should work fine.

Comment: I am using . net framework 4 but there are some references which built using framework 4.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you follow these steps:

- In Solution Explorer, right-click the project node and click Add
  Reference.
- In the Add Reference dialog box, select the tab indicating
  the type of component you want to reference.
- Select the components you want to reference, and then click OK.

And possible remedies of the error:

- A common cause is a simple misspelling where the class name is used.
- If the name is correct then the next most likely cause is that the required namespace has not been included
- If the name is correct and the necessary namespace has been included then check the framework version. Not all classes and types are available for all frameworks. For example "SempahoreSlim" was introduced with the .Net framework 4, which means that you will get an error trying to use it if you are targeting a .NET framework earlier than the .NET 4 framework after including a reference to System.Threading