# The type or namespace name 'xxx' could not be found

Tags: c#, dll, c#-2.0

I've developed a dll in .net 2.0. Now I need that dll to be used in other project in the same solution. The project that I am using is also on .net 2.0. It is showing me an error of could not be found.

If I change the target platform from .net 2.0 to 3.5 it works fine in the main project.

Please help me in this.

Comment: Please open project references and check that error dll properties copy local=true; or check  your dll  compatibilities for .net 2.0.

Comment: @AkınAbdullahoğlu checked it is already there.

Comment: I research this problem and found few result. Please check this links. Main Problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286599/referenced-project-gets-lost-at-compile-time And Solved : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4765076/3041974

Comment: @AkınAbdullahoğlu I did checked. when I run the dll project in 2.0 it is giving me the output and when I refer it in .net 3.5 project its working but i need it in .net 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Problem was with the dll that has been refer with in the dll xxx that I need to use in project. The dll is refers two more dll with in it so I need to add reference of both of that dll in main project and then I can use using xxx statement.